# SAML authentication using Azure AD with .NET Core 6 and Angular - CORS error

Tags: angularjs, .net-core, azure-active-directory, cors, saml

Using .NET Core 6, I managed to successfully use cookie saml2 authentication using Azure AD as IDP, and the SP being my backend API. Tested with Swagger and it works as expected.

I'm using these methods below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
    binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

    return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
        {
            ForceAuthn = true,
            
            AssertionConsumerServiceUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44318/Auth/AssertionConsumerService")
        }).ToActionResult();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
{
    var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
    var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

    binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);

    if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
    }

    binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
    await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));

    var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
    var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
    var isAuth = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    //returnUrl = "http://localhost:4200/userloggedin/";
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

[HttpPost("Logout")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }

    var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
    var saml2LogoutRequest = await new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, User).DeleteSession(HttpContext);

    return binding.Bind(saml2LogoutRequest).ToActionResult();
}
```

However, when sending request from the frontend Angular.JS project, I am getting a CORS error.

I did try:

1. Enable CORS in my backend API (though Azure is throwing the CORS error, not my backend project)
2. Add return urls properly in Azure ad saml configuration
3. Use reverse proxy in Angular.JS and it fixes the issue, but I am going to have different domains or subdomains when in production, so it is just a local solution unfortunately.

`localhost:4200` is my frontend project, `localhost:44318` is my .NET Core backend API

Screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: AngularJS and modern Angular (2+) are distinct frameworks. It looks like you meant the latter?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are performing an XHR request, however you cannot do this for SAML authentication.

You'll want to navigate to your API endpoint, i.e. your "Login" endpoint, either via a link or a full page redirect (e.g. `window.location.href = 'https://localhost:44318/api/v2/some-login-endpoint';`). This will then:

- Redirect to the Microsoft Azure SAML URL
- Redirect to your Assertion URL on your API with any relay state (it looks like only your Return URL, for now)
- Redirect to the appropriate UI URL (e.g. `https://localhost:4200/some-url`), which you'll have initially sent via the `returnUrl` query string parameter when performing the initial navigation to your Login endpoint (e.g. `https://localhost:44318/api/v2/some-login-endpoint?returnUrl=https://localhost:4200/some-url`).

You could also do it via a pop-up, however the code for this would need to be different.

Comment: Yeah, when logging in for the first time, it's solved this way, but every other request after logging in/authenticating is still redirecting to microsoft, so I think I will need to fix xhr requests as you mentioned, using a popup you mean with iframe?

Comment: Instead of a full page redirect, you can (depending on the provider), open the SAML API Login endpoint in a pop-up. At the end of the flow, when it redirects to your "Return URL", you can instead close the pop-up and post a message back to the main window via the JavaScript `postMessage` feature. This isn't necessary though, and I imagine your current approach is fine. 

I'd need to see the rest of your code to understand why it keeps trying to login again. Perhaps the cookie isn't being set correctly, or there's some other configuration issue?